# getting a blank white page in when I use route indicate to method in controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

I have this controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Student;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CourseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return 'okay' ;
    }
}
```

and when I call the method index he return a blank white page :

the route:

```
Route::get('/student/course' , [\App\Http\Controllers\Student\CourseController::class , 'index'])->name('student.course.index');
```

and when I write

```
php artisan route:list
```

I get the right route name like:

```
  GET|HEAD        student/course ............ student.course.index › Student\CourseController@index
```

how can I fix this error

I tried to press ctrl from the route and I'd go to the right controller and the right method
but why he return a blank white page I don't know
any one can help me?

Comment: I presume when you say call the method index you mean visit the route in your browser?

Comment: in my browser and in view page 
I tried all the method to call it

Comment: try returning a view or echo a string.

Comment: I tried that but he return a blank white page

Comment: I think you are getting a cached view, try `php artisan cache:clear` to clear the cache

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following command.

```
php artisan optimize
```

After using this command your problem should be solved, otherwise you should check the namespace.

Comment: I tried this command but it doesn't work 
and the namespace is correct